# Rainfall trend analysis in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, time-series, analysis

I have an image collection of images representing total seaonal rainfall from 1980-2020 in my study area. I want to run an analysis which identifies if a pixel has any significant trends i.e. significantly less total rainfall in seasons 2010-2020 than 1980-2010 - or something along those lines.

If I was using rainfall station point data I would run an ANOVA in R (more experience in R than GEE) so I am looking for something similar or better for this analysis in Google Earth Engine for my images- any ideas?

Key is I want to identify statistically significant decreases/increases in rainfall.

Comment: Maybe try doing a linear regression https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/reducers_regression